# Understanding formula for Short Term / Long Term Degrees of freedom in minitab

Tags: degrees-of-freedom, minitab

Now I'm new to statistics, but the last time I did degrees of freedom, the formula I used was

$df = n-1,$

but I've just been playing with Minitab and reading the help to files, and I noticed it is calculating long-term and short-term degrees of freedom like this:

$df(LT) = \sum_{i=1}^j n_j-1$

$df(ST) = \sum_{i=1}^j (n_j-1)$

I interpret it like this:

Data (1 group): 20, 10 ,10, 23, 25, 20

$df(LT) = (20+10+10+23+25+20) - 1$

$df(LT) = 108$

and

$df(ST) = ((20-1)+(10-1)+(10-1)+(23-1)+(25-1)+(20-1))$

$df(ST) = 102$

I have got this right, or am I way out?

UPDATE:
Looking around other help files, I found that
$n_j$ is the number of obervartions in the jth subgroup.

So with that in mind, and my example with only 1 subgroup, I assume that both LT and ST are the same, which is $n - 1$.

Comment: Does 20, 10 ,10, 23, 25, 20 represent how many observations are in each group, or the dependent variable? Normally n refers to how many observations is in a sample.

Comment: dependent variable, there is only 1 group.

Comment: I'm not sure why they'd have a subscript j if there's only 1 group. Maybe if you posted up where these formulas were found other people might be able to help.

Comment: You can have many groups, but my data only has 1. Just about to update with more info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are close, but off the mark. While "long-term" and "short-term" are new to me (indeed, they seem to be specific to [this site](https://support.minitab.com/en-us/minitab/18/help-and-how-to/quality-and-process-improvement/six-sigma/how-to/process-report/methods-and-formulas/calculations-for-process-statistics-and-capability-values/#degrees-of-freedom) and might as well come with a trademark!) I can tell you that you seem to be calculating the whole-sample variance degrees of freedom (LT) and the anova denominator degrees of freedom (ST), which could also be described as the mean squared error (MSE) degrees of freedom.

To be clear, the values of $n_i$ are the *number of measurements* in group $i$, not the *actual measurements*. The total number of measurements $n$ of data acquired from $J$ groups is $$n=\sum_{i=1}^J n_i.$$ The LT degrees of freedom seems to be $n-1$, which would be the number used in the unbiased estimate of the whole-sample variance $$s^2=\frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{k=1}^n(x_k-\bar{x})^2.$$ Here the $x_k$ does correspond to the actual data, and $\bar{x}$ is the whole-sample mean, sometimes called the grand mean.

The short-term degrees of freedom correspond to $n-J$, which is the total number of points acquired minus the number of groups (or treatments) $J$. This would be the degrees of freedom used in calculating the variance within treatments for the group-wise model.

$$
MSE = \frac{1}{n-J} \sum_{i=1}^J \sum_{k=1}^{n_i} \left( x_k^{(i)}-\bar{x}^{(i)} \right)^2,
$$
where $i$ is the index for $J$ treatments or groups, $x_k^{(i)}$ is the $k$-th data point in group $i$, and $\bar{x}^{(i)}$ is the sample mean of the $i$-th group. This would be the denominator of the F test of equal means of $J% groups, and $n-J$ would be the denominator degrees of freedom.

---

I see that the Minitab page uses $\mu$ to describe a *sample* average. Argh! This is highly non-standard notation. Greek letters are (nearly-universally) reserved for population parameters, not sample statistics. The (nearly-universally) recognized notation for a sample statistic is the Roman letter. In this case, the sample average is $\bar{x}.$ Hopefully you are not confused by this nonstandard notation. Population parameters are only ever *estimated* by sample statistics. They themselves are not statistics, at all.

Comment: Perfect!, thank you. The doucmentation is not great as I am finding more details about the mathmatical notation in various documents.